# On Linux, how do I take the TIFF that SANE's scanimage outputs and convert it to a JPEG with a pipe character?

Tags: linux, sane

I was thinking of using Imagemagick's convert program, as my preferred program nconvert doesn't work on the ARM CPU of the Raspberry pi.

Comment: Imacemagick `convert` works very well under Windows and Linux x86.  I'd certainly give it a try.

Comment: So if SANE's `scanimage` outputs a TIFF, how do I direct that to `convert` so that the end result is a JPEG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [`convert` documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) , you can use a `tiff:-` to represent a tiff file on the standard input or output stream.  And [scanimage docs](http://www.sane-project.org/man/scanimage.1.html) say you need to give the format to get TIFF.  Putting this together, you'd have:

```
scanimage --format=tiff | convert tiff:- scan.jpg
```

I don't have access to a machine where I can test this.

Comment: That works well, thanks. But it looks like the pi's measly amount of RAM isn't able to convert larger scans without doing a lot of swapping. I'll have to set up a TIFF-JPEG conversion watch folder on the Windows server that the pi scans to. (this is for a project where I scan plants multiple times an hour for weeks) Any idea on how I would set such a watch folder up?

Comment: Yes, Pi's RAM is a limitatation.  I'm not sure I understand your question.  I'd set up Samba to connect to a writeable share on the Windows box.  Have the Windows run a task in Scheduler to do conversions.  The only trick is mutex:  preventing the Windows machine from trying to convert a partially written scan.  To prevent this, you could have the Pi write a second file for each scan connoting that it's complete. Don't try to convert any scan where this file isn't yet present.  File locks like this are a time-honored way of synchronizing shared resources.

Comment: Good idea. I have a Samba connection between them. Good idea for preventing premature conversions. Could you point me to resources/examples that would help someone without any scripting knowledge like me do what you're describing, both on the Windows side with scheduler, and also on the Pi side? On the Pi side, I use SANE's scanimage's batch function, which automatically adds a numbering scheme with each serial scan. How would you make a shell script that could add the signifying file after each image was created?

Answer (score 1):

Specify `-` as the input file to `convert` – e.g.,

```
scanimage | convert - output.jpg
```